# Any tank mates for an African clawed frog

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium, frogs

My aunt keeps forgetting to feed her African clawed frog and offered it to me. I think this frog would be cool with other fish or amphibians but I've also heard of them eating some. I would like to know if there are any suitable options for a 10 or 20 gallon tank. I would also like to know if there are any live plant options.

Comment: Don't put goldfish or Mollies in with African Clawed Frogs. I was given an aquatic frog. It turned out to be an African Clawed Frog not the dwarf variety they believed it to be. As it grew bigger than the dwarf it shredded the fins of the fancy goldfish and then started on the scales. one scale at a time. Unfortunetly I did not notice this until it was to late. The goldfish never recovered even after moving them to a different tank. It seems to be OK with an 8in. Rhino Placastomus because its skin is so tough, but Im keeping an eye on the tail fins. I came to this site to ask the same question

Answer (score 2):

Try fancy guppies or balloon mollies. They are both suitable for 10-20 gallons and are top dwelling fish, community fish, so they'll add color and life to your tank with little interaction with your dwarf frog, and won't pick on him. I've learned they're hardier than most think. Plant recommendations would be Dwarf Anubias or Moss balls. Check out this list in link:

https://www.myfroggycam.com/using-live-plants-in-an-african-dwarf-frog-tank.php

Comment: Also just found this link.     http://aquaticfrogs.tripod.com/id26.html

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I have to answer this, even if I am too late!

Beware of the differences between [Dwarf Frogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_dwarf_frog) and [African Clawed Frogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_clawed_frog). The second wikipedia article there even says:

> African clawed frogs are frequently mislabeled as African dwarf frogs in pet stores. The astute pet owner will recognize the difference, however, because of the following characteristics:
>
> -Dwarf frogs have four webbed feet. African clawed frogs have webbed hind feet while their front feet have autonomous digits.
>
> -African dwarf frogs have eyes positioned on the side of their head, while African clawed frogs have eyes on the top of their heads.
>
> -African clawed frogs have curved, flat snouts. The snout of an African dwarf frog is pointed.

It's important because the clawed ones grow a fair bit bigger than the dwarf ones (the size of the palm of your hand or bigger, even though they start off the size of your fingernail!) and will eat whatever fits in their mouths. And their mouths are pretty big relative to their heads. As their name suggests, they also have claws and can perform some crazy yoga to claw at the "food" they're currently putting in their mouth. Personally, I think they could and would eat a molly once they're fully grown.